# How to fill in row value based on previous and subsequent rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, apply

I have the following data. There are consecutive runs of `True` per day, however sometimes there's the odd `False` for a day followed by `True`.

Due to the nature of this data, it appears this is an error, therefore, I need to replace these odd `False`s with **True**, if the 'sandwiched' **False** only lasts 1 day.

For `False`s that are *not* *between* `True`s, I want them to remain the same.

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'start_datetime' : [
        '2019-04-29 00:00:00','2019-04-30 00:00:00','2019-05-01 00:00:00','2019-05-02 00:00:00','2019-05-03 00:00:00','2019-05-07 00:00:00','2019-05-08 00:00:00','2019-05-09 00:00:00','2019-05-10 00:00:00','2019-05-14 00:00:00'],
    'diag_local_code' : [
        True,
        True,
        True,
        True,
        False,
        True,
        True,
        False,
        False,
        False
    ],
    
})

>>>
    start_datetime      diag_local_code
0   2019-04-29 00:00:00 True
1   2019-04-30 00:00:00 True
2   2019-05-01 00:00:00 True
3   2019-05-02 00:00:00 True
4   2019-05-03 00:00:00 False
5   2019-05-07 00:00:00 True
6   2019-05-08 00:00:00 True
7   2019-05-09 00:00:00 False
8   2019-05-10 00:00:00 False
9   2019-05-14 00:00:00 False
```

Comment: In your example, only row 4 needs to be `True`?

Comment: Do you use "odd" in the mathematical sense (i.e. not even)?

Comment: Odd in terms of the colloquial sense apologies - i.e. replacing the random Falses that don't seem to be correct

Answer (score 0):

Let's say ths dataframe is df:

```
for i in df.index:
    if df['diag_local_code'].iloc[i] == False and df['diag_local_code'].iloc[i-1]==True and df['diag_local_code'].iloc[i+1]==True:
        df['diag_local_code'].iloc[i]=True
```

This worked for me!

Comment: If my df is quite large (around 30K rows), is the solution by @simon better in terms of speed just because of the for loop? I'm not too sure

Comment: Maybe, you can try it for yourself if you have the time

Answer (score 0):

```
# Setup

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_datetime' : [
        '2019-04-29 00:00:00','2019-04-30 00:00:00','2019-05-01 00:00:00','2019-05-02 00:00:00','2019-05-03 00:00:00','2019-05-07 00:00:00','2019-05-08 00:00:00','2019-05-09 00:00:00','2019-05-10 00:00:00','2019-05-14 00:00:00'],
    'diag_local_code' : [
        True,
        True,
        True,
        True,
        False,
        True,
        True,
        False,
        False,
        False
    ],
    
})

# Shift to get row above and below

df['next'] = df['diag_local_code'].shift(-1)
df['previous'] = df['diag_local_code'].shift(1)

# Filter
condition = ((df['next'] == True)) & (df['previous'] == True) & (df['diag_local_code'] == False)
# Assign value
df[condition] = True
```

Comment: Is this solution faster than the for loop provided by man0s? (see my comment to his answer)

Comment: @chillingfox It should. Column wise based operations are nearly always faster than looping. It’s why databases are designed that way.